# ngrx: get value from the store before load page

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have page component, inside that I'm displaying some data from `ngrx/store`:

```
// profile.ts
user$: User = this.store.select('user')
```

```
// profile.html
...

<div *ngIf="user$ | async; let user">
  <div>{{user.id}}</div>  
  <div>{{user.email}}</div>
</div>
```

This works, but I don't like that it initially loads the page without data, and then after 1 sec add this data from the `user$`. I understand this is how it should be - because I'm using async pipe, but I want to change it.

What options do I have? Can I somehow preload this `user` selection from the store, to have it in all components, so that I don’t need to request them from the store every time, because of this, all the pages where I get some data from the store “flickering” after loading?

Comment: I know that pain. From the top of my head, would a resolve guard help here?
https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard
However, I'm not so sure about the ngrx aspect of this question, if it works well with a resolve guard / resolver service.

Comment: In angular guard or resolver, dispatch an action to fetch the data and in ngrx effect call the service. Make sure to wait for the API call to come back before resolving the route. See the example - https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app

Comment: You're always going to have the subscription in your components, but have you considered moving the population of the user data to an application initializer function that is called by your module? The function can dispatch the action to load the user data from your service to populate state as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to to not fetch data if it's already in the store, would be inside an effect - [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#4-using-a-selector-inside-your-effects) by myself.

```
@Effect()
getOrder = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<GetOrder>(ActionTypes.GetOrder),
  withLatestFrom(action =>
    of(action).pipe(
      this.store.pipe(select(getOrders))
    )
  ),
  filter(([{payload}, orders]) => !!orders[payload.orderId])
  mergeMap([{payload}] => {
    ...
  })
)
```

But I think what you're looking for are Angular router guards to fetch the data and load the page once you have the data in your store.
See [Preloading ngrx store with Route Guards](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards) by Todd Motto for more info.

```
@Injectable()
export class CoursesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<CoursesState>) {}

  getFromStoreOrAPI(): Observable<any> {
    return this.store
      .select(getCoursesState)
      .do((data: any) => {
        if (!data.courses.length) {
          this.store.dispatch(new Courses.CoursesGet());
        }
      })
      .filter((data: any) => data.courses.length)
      .take(1);
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getFromStoreOrAPI()
      .switchMap(() => of(true))
      .catch(() => of(false));
  }
}
```

For the (the best?) UX you can also use ghost elements - [Great User Experiences with Ghost Elements](https://blog.angularindepth.com/@thomasburlesonIA) by Thomas Burleson.