# Ngrx/effects: wait for user data in store, before load page

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have `user.service`, where I fetch user data on page load from database and save them to store via `user.action`:

```
export class UserService {
   user$ = this.store.select('user')

   constructor(
      private fireStore: AngularFirestore,
      private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
      private store: Store<AppState>
   ) {
     this.fireAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        const { uid } = auth

        this.fireStore.collection('users').doc(uid).ref.get()
        .then(data => {
          const user = data.data() as User

          this.store.dispatch(new UserActions.SaveUser(user))
        })
      } else {
        this.store.dispatch(new UserActions.RemoveUser())
      }
    })
   }
}
```

So, if database return user data - I save them to store, and if not - it's mean user is not logged in, and I remove user data from 'user' store.

I want my home page to wait until data is fetched with `User.service` before load, so I think I have to create Effect for this:

```
export class UserEffects {

  @Effect()
  loadUser$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.SAVE_USER),
    map(user => user)
  )

  constructor (
    private actions$: Actions,
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {}
}
```

But if I do it like this, Application begins to endlessly dispatch `UserActions.SAVE_USER` action:
[image]
How should I do it in correct way?

Comment: Just as a further thing... if you want to load this before app starts: https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER or you can use a route resolver: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngrx: get value from the store before load page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508961/ngrx-get-value-from-the-store-before-load-page)

Answer (score 0):

You should make actions, for example getUsers and setUser that are dispatched when you start your App, or route to /home. Also in your reducers make those two in your switch(actionType) to store/modify your state. After that you just bind effect on getUsers with @Effect(), so whenever getUsers is going to be called, also effect is going to be called and from there setUser is called in your reducer. For reference, check this 2 articles:

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/ngrx-tutorial-actions-reducers-and-effects/

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/ngrx-tutorial-add-state-to-feature-module/

To trigger your data load, you could use [Angular Lazy Loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) on your route, for example: localhost:4200/home

Edit: also there is no need for your service, just implement it directly in your effect.